# NLA Animated strip time with cyclic strip time reverses the motion

Tags: nla-editor

I created two quick walk and running animations for practice purposes using Rigify animbox. Blender version is 3.6.0.

In the NLA I'm trying to blend between the two actions, but when I activate the animated strip time + cyclic strip time for the bottom action (the run cycle) it makes the run cycle, well, run backwards. Both the walk and run cycle has animated strip time + cyclic strip time activated. I'm not sure what's causing this. The Blend file + a video example will be shared here. Any help is hugely appreciated!

Video demonstration - https://youtu.be/f3xY0Y83l0k

Comment: I don't know why the Animated Strip Time makes it go backwards but if you want to fix that you can keyframe the Strip Time value, what were you trying to do with the Animated Strip Time by the way? It is made to slow down or speed up the action, or play it bacwards...

Comment: I was sorta fiddling around to try and figure out the use case scenarios for complex animations. Your suggestion about keyframing the strip value instantly fixed it! Thank you so much! Is there a way to flag this question as solved?

Comment: I'm going to answer in the Your Answer field and you can validate my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the *Animated Strip Time* makes it go backwards in your case but if you want to fix that you can keyframe the *Strip Time* value. *Animated Strip Time* is made to slow down or speed up the action, or play it bacwards. The *Strip Time* value is the frame of the selected action that you want to be played at frame X. If you put a value of 1 at frame 1 and a value of 23 at frame 23 it will play the action at its normal speed. If you put a value of 23 at frame 11 for example the action will be played at twice its speed, etc.

Comment: Validated! Thank you so much!